# Generate URLs from database code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-4.0, vb.net-2010

This in ref to this question that i asked but never got answered [ASP.NET 4 ACCESS DATA TO APPLY TO NavigateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348260/asp-net-4-access-data-to-apply-to-navigateurl) but suppose thats redundant now.

I need to generate dynamic URLs from a database in code behind and then use them in a list view but i cannot find anywhere on the internet or in my book that covers something like this.

Im getting data out using below in a code behind page:

```
    'portfolio navigation data
    Dim rdrPortfolioNav As SqlDataReader

    Dim cmdPortfolioNav As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    cmdPortfolioNav.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 6 [id], [date], [client], [category], [title], [body], [website], [navimage], [navdesc] FROM [portfolio] ORDER BY [date] DESC"
    cmdPortfolioNav.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdPortfolioNav.Connection = boomSQL

    cmdPortfolioNav.Connection.Open()
    rdrPortfolioNav = cmdPortfolioNav.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    lvPortfolioNav.DataSource = rdrPortfolioNav
    lvPortfolioNav.DataBind()

    cmdPortfolioNav.Dispose()
```

there will be multiple records returned and i need to then concatenate to generate URLs from fields in the data e.g. "portfolio/" & [id] & "/" & [category] & "/" & [title] and then display these in a list view with the concatenated text being the NavigateUrl:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvPortfolioNav" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="work">
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="" ToolTip=""><span class="title"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title")%></span></asp:HyperLink>
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, &quot;navimage&quot;)%>" AlternateText="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, &quot;client&quot;)%>" ToolTip="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, &quot;client&quot;)%>" />
                        <span class="desc"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "navdesc")%></span>
                    </div>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Can anyone help or at least get me started on how to loop through each record on the code behind page to generate all the urls then how to show these on the actual page within the list view.

Much appreciated,

J.

Comment: Can't you use DataBound events?

Comment: hi, sorry i'm very new to .net and am currently teaching myself, this is why i'm struggling, so don't really know what you mean....sorry.

Comment: I see that my listview is bound to the data, do i just do the same for the ID of my asp:HyperLink?? any example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the NavigateUrl property on your HyperLink to something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("portfolio/{0}/{1}/{2}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "category"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title")) %>' ToolTip="">
```

Comment: I found this out late yesterday afternoon but thanks for the reply, it seemd the double quotes NavigateUrl="" i was using were causing the problem, although yet to find out why!